# What does a method turn into with the equal sign left out in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've just found out that it's possible not to use the sign of `=` when defining a method in Scala.

```
def someMethod(a: Int) {
  println(a)
  println("---------")
}
```

What's the difference between the above version and one with the equals sign after the parameter list and the opening curly bracket `{`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Such method definition is called `procedure`. It's a special syntax for `Unit`-returning methods:

```
def someMethod(a: Int): Unit = {
  println(a)
  println("---------")
}
```

It's not a recommended syntax. 
Martin Odersky believes it was a bad decision to include this syntax. See [Keynote - Scala with Style chapter 45](http://www.parleys.com/play/51c1994ae4b0d38b54f4621b/chapter45/about).

Comment: Huh, Scala Style Guide recommends, in opposite, to always use the shorter syntax for void methods: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#void_methods

Comment: opsss, does Scala have 3 types of methods: methods themselves, functions and procedures? I've known only about the first 2.

Comment: @MariusKavansky: `procedure declaration` is the name of special syntax for method declaration. It's just a regular method with return type `Unit`.

Comment: @esycat: The recommendation against using the equal-less `Unit`-returning syntax by Martin Odersky himself is a recent one.

Comment: Eleven upvotes?  If eleven people were unsure enough about procedures to upvote, then they definitely have to get rid of the syntax.

Comment: On the contrary, I am sure the `procedure syntax` is bad, that's one of many reason of up vote the answer.

Comment: IntelliJ for long time recommended procedure syntax BTW. (Now it is off by default, saying "This inspection became deprecated"). As a result, I have procedure syntax all over the place. Still, I think if you have a rather mutable style, e.g. writing in serialisation or a lot of STM based things, the `: Unit =` can become a bit noisy. I liked Simon's experiment with removing curly braces, though.

Comment: @0__: What experiment do you mean?