# When should a Scala method def use an explicitly defined return type?

Tags: scala, coding-style

Scala-style-guide suggest to always explicitly define return type expect when used `Unit`:

> Methods should be declared according to the following pattern:
>
> ```
> def foo(bar: Baz): Bin = expr
> ```
>
> The only exceptions to this rule are methods which return Unit. Such
>   methods should use Scala's syntactic sugar to avoid accidentally
>   confusing return types:
>
> ```
> def foo(bar: Baz) { // return type is Unit
>   expr
> }
> ```

Comment: Martin Odersky recommends to avoid procedure syntax. See [Keynote - Scala with Style chapter 45](http://www.parleys.com/play/51c1994ae4b0d38b54f4621b/chapter45/about). See also discussion in comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17502581/406435).

Comment: @senia ok, if procedure syntax is bad, so what is better: explicitly declare `Unit` as return type or omit it (compiler will infer type himself)?

Comment: just like any other type. In some guides it's recommended to specify type explicitly in public methods. I guess it's a primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: Btw, if you write a recursive function, the return type is mandatory.

Comment: And you usually should define return types in your public API, to hide implementation specific types.

Answer (score 2):

As commentators have pointed out, Martin Odersky discusses this in the linked Keynote. Of course, as "when should..." indicates, this is ultimately a stylistic question, so one can only give an opinion.

Two things: (1) Types yes/no, and (2) Procedure syntax yes/no.

---

(1) Obviously with pure API (without implementations) you must specify the return type. I would extend this to any method implementation which is also at the same time **API**. I.e., if your method is not implementing a trait—in which case the compiler will give you an error when your return type differs—, you should annotate the method. **Private and local** methods are fine to have the return type inferred, unless you find it difficult to figure out the type at the first glance, or you are forced (e.g. in a recursive method call). It is also said that the compilation is *faster* when you give explicit return types.

If you have short methods with an **"easy"** return type, I think inference is fine. Ex.

```
trait Foo {
  def sqrt(d: Double) = math.sqrt(d)

  def toString = "Foo"

  def bar = new Bar(123)
}
```

(But already someone could argue that it might not be obvious that `math.sqrt` returns a `Double`).

Although more verbose, you make the code more readable and you avoid (a) **leaking** information about an implementation or sub-type where a super-type sufficies:

```
trait Before {
  def bar = new BarImpl

  def seq = Vector(1, 2, 3)
}

trait After {
  def bar: Bar = new BarImpl

  def seq: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
}
```

And (b) you avoid **accidentally** returning something you didn't intend to, from structural type to wrong collection type etc.

---

(2) Until recently I preferred procedure syntax, but after renewed discussion and many people voicing their discontent with it, I tried using the explicit `: Unit =` annotation, and I like it more now. I thought procedure syntax makes it clear that a method has a side effect, but indeed `: Unit =` does carry that indication quite clearly, too. Also it often removes the amount of curly braces:

```
trait Before {
  private var _x = 0
  def x: Int = _x
  def x_=(value: Int) { _x = value }
}
```

versus

```
trait After {
  private var _x = 0
  def x: Int = _x
  def x_=(value: Int): Unit = _x = value  // if double = confuses you, use new line?
}
```

I found many cases where the body begins with an `if`, a pattern `match`, `synchronized` block or `future` generation, a collection `map` expression etc., and in these cases removing the curly braces is nice:

```
trait Before {
  def connect()(implicit tx: Tx) {
    values.foreach { case (x, _) =>
      x.changed += this
    }
  }
}

trait After {
  def connect()(implicit tx: Tx): Unit =
    values.foreach { case (x, _) =>
      x.changed += this
    }
}
```